# Do the Wolf Puppy and Madison rules stack?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

While playing the Witch's bonus round I got the Wolf Puppy rule which states "Both you and your enemies start each fight with Fury". Later on I had the option to also take Madison which says "Enemies start each fight with Fury".

If I had gotten the rules for both Wolf Puppy and Madison, would enemies have had two stacks of Fury to triple their first action?